# "kBrushless cannot be resolved or is not a field" error in FRC Java

Tags: java, mfrc522

Importer "kBrushless" states that is is not resolved of not a field. Any help?

```
    /*----------------------------------------------------------------------------*/
/* Copyright (c) 2017-2018 FIRST. All Rights Reserved.                        */
/* Open Source Software - may be modified and shared by FRC teams. The code   */
/* must be accompanied by the FIRST BSD license file in the root directory of */
/* the project.                                                               */
/*----------------------------------------------------------------------------*/

package frc.robot;

import edu.wpi.first.wpilibj.Joystick;
import edu.wpi.first.wpilibj.TimedRobot;
import edu.wpi.first.wpilibj.drive.RobotDriveBase.MotorType;
import edu.wpi.first.wpilibj.GenericHID;
import edu.wpi.first.wpilibj.Joystick;
import edu.wpi.first.wpilibj.XboxController;
import edu.wpi.first.wpilibj2.command.Command;

import edu.wpi.first.wpilibj2.command.InstantCommand;
import edu.wpi.first.wpilibj2.command.button.JoystickButton;
// import edu.wpi.first.hal.FRCNetComm.tResourceType;
// import edu.wpi.first.hal.HAL;

import frc.robot.autos.*;
import frc.robot.commands.*;
import frc.robot.subsystems.*;

public class Robot2 extends TimedRobot {
  private static final int leadDeviceID = 1;
  private static final int followDeviceID = 2;
  private static final int kJoystickPort = 0;

  private CANSparkMax m_leadMotor;
  private CANSparkMax m_followMotor;
  private Joystick m_joystick;

  @Override
  public void robotInit() {
   
    m_leadMotor = new CANSparkMax(leadDeviceID, MotorType.kBrushless);
    m_followMotor = new CANSparkMax(followDeviceID, MotorType.kBrushless);

    m_leadMotor.restoreFactoryDefaults();
    m_followMotor.restoreFactoryDefaults();
 }

}
```

This is also using the WPI libraries and FRC. This is also using all of the imported libraries, as it is shown below.

Comment: [That class](https://first.wpi.edu/wpilib/allwpilib/docs/release/java/edu/wpi/first/wpilibj/drive/RobotDriveBase.MotorType.html) does not have that constant. Are you using a different version of that library? Or where did you get the `kBrushless` from?

Comment: this is using the ->

Comment: import edu.wpi.first.gradlerio.deploy.roborio.RoboRIO

plugins {
    id "java"
    id "edu.wpi.first.GradleRIO" version "2022.2.1"
}

Comment: show the exact compiler error

Answer (score 1):

You are importing the wrong `MotorType` enum:

- the [`edu.wpi.first.wpilibj.drive.RobotDriveBase.MotorType`](https://first.wpi.edu/wpilib/allwpilib/docs/release/java/edu/wpi/first/wpilibj/drive/RobotDriveBase.MotorType.html) doesn't contain a `kBrushless` constant.
- it seems that you are using [`CANSparkMax`](https://codedocs.revrobotics.com/java/com/revrobotics/cansparkmax) (because you write `m_leadMotor = new CANSparkMax(leadDeviceID, MotorType.kBrushless);`)
- the [`CANSparkMax` constructor](https://codedocs.revrobotics.com/java/com/revrobotics/cansparkmax#%3Cinit%3E(int,com.revrobotics.CANSparkMaxLowLevel.MotorType) takes as second parameter an instance of [`CANSparkMaxLowLevel.MotorType`](https://codedocs.revrobotics.com/java/com/revrobotics/cansparkmaxlowlevel.motortype), which **has** a constant `kBrushless`

Therefore it seems that you should replace

```
import edu.wpi.first.wpilibj.drive.RobotDriveBase.MotorType;
```

with

```
import com.revrobotics.CANSparkMaxLowLevel.MotorType;
```

and probably also add

```
import com.revrobotics.CANSparkMax;
```